# Why does an SQL table have multiple primary keys?

Tags: sql, primary-key, primary-key-design

On my job (non programming job that takes advantage of some of my programming skills), I was asked to generate a report from our outsourced, custom made program's SQL database.

When looking at the tables I see that many of them have multiple fields assigned as PK, why is that? What advantage does that have over a serial, numeric id?

Comment: "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data integrity. A key means a uniqueness constraint that prevents duplicate data entering the database. Keys help ensure that facts in the database can be properly identified with the real-world objects or concepts that they are supposed to describe. In practice not everything can or should be identified by a single attribute in a single column.

Note: A key with more than one attribute is not multiple keys. It's still just one key (called a *composite key*).

Answer (score 1):

It is called a composite key. If `order_no` is primary key in table `Order` and in table `Order_Item` there is a unique sequence number within order assigned to each order item, i.e. all orders have items beginning with sequence number 1 then the primary key for Order_Item would be `order_no, item_sequence_no`.

Contrast this with a generated primary key for `Order_Item`: you would still need a unique index on `order_no, item_sequence_no`. If you think about the queries you might find that more rely on the composite key.

The business dependent and system generated keys are technically known as domain key and surrogate key respectively. [c2 wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AutoKeysVersusDomainKeys) has a good discussion on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes multiple values in a table will form a natural primary key, as opposed to a surrogate, auto-generated primary key.

A few of the advantages of this would be that if those multiple values uniquely identify a record, then the PK enforces uniqueness, and in MS SQL Server, by default that PK will also be the clustered index on the table.

Comment: As regards the clustered index, the order of the columns in the PK definition could be crucial.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the table and the columns used as PK.

If the table if question is a join table used in many-to-many association, then you can use a composite primary key from the foreign key columns (as their combination will be unique in join table) and no additional synthetic primary keys will be needed.

Other example is a natural key, when some combination of existing column values can be used to uniquely refer to a row in table (for example, first and last name for people). They aren't much used, as most such candidate natural keys don't have desired properties (that is, they are not unique or not immutable).

Comment: "most such candidate natural keys are not really keys (that is, they are not unique" -- that makes no sense.

Comment: "They aren't much used, as most... are not... immutable" -- a property of a good key is stability. Consider that SQL's `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is in the language in recognition that key values may change.

Comment: doesn't stability mean that key values shouldn't change? And immutability means exactly that?

Comment: Joe Celko: "stability is over time. You do not want keys changing 
frequently or in unpredictable ways. Contrary to a popular myth, this does not mean that keys cannot ever change.  As the scope of their context grows, they should be able to change." Example: [ISBN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) changed from 10 to 13 digits. Immutability is nice to have, of course, but is not a requirement for a key.